# MediaRecorder Web API: how to pause/resume Audio Stream (Mic)

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

I am recording from mic using this:

```
const micStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false });
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const audioDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
const userAudio = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);
userAudio.connect(audioDestination);
const tracks = audioDestination.stream.getTracks();
const fullStream = new MediaStream(tracks);
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(fullStream);

recordedChunks = [];

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
  recordedChunks.push(e.data);
};

[... creating a Blob and uploading it ...]
```

I would like to implement a pause/resume button. But I don't see any pause/resume method in any of these classes:

- [MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices)
- [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream)
- [MediaStreamTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack)

How can I implement a mic pause/resume functionality? (even if it is just *muting* the mic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To implement a way for users to mute and unmute a track, use the
> [enabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/enabled) property. When a track is disabled by setting enabled to
> false, it generates only empty frames (audio frames in which every
> sample is 0, or video frames in which every pixel is black).

- [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/muted)

Comment: Can we play a record, while the streaming on pause? I didn't find a solution